# How do I create a Dictionary from two Lists, that is compatible with iOS and other Unity platforms?

Tags: c#, ios, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I read in some of the [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) that a `Dictionary` isn't serializable so can't be modified from the editor. There was a hint to use two `List`s, then use them to create the `Dictionary`:

> Hint: Unity won't serialize Dictionary, however you could store a
>   List<> for keys and a List<> for values, and sew them up in a non
>   serialized dictionary on Awake().

However I don't seem to be able to find the documentation to do just that. So far I have the following:

```
public List<string> someKeys;
public List<Sprite> someValues;

private void Awake()
{
    someDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Sprite>();
}
```

`someKeys` and `someValues` are setup and populated in the Unity editor with the same number of elements. Naturally, element 0 of `someKeys` is the key for element 0 in `someValues`, as do the rest of the keys in order. **How can I now use them both to create the keys and values in the `someDictionary`?**

**Update:** I see from the duplicate marks that this has been answered using `Linq`, which as a newbie to C# I've not used yet, but certainly seems to do the job. But would this be safe in Unity, especially on devices like those running iOS? Additionally, would this method be better (i.e. faster and/or considered better practice than using a standard `for` loop?

*Note:* I want to access the `Sprite`s in `someValues` by their key, not by a numerical index.

Comment: For each index n in the list add the n-th key and the n-th value to the dictionary.

Comment: i think rather then a dictionary of two lists, a list of dictionary will be fine.

Comment: I've edited my question to provide more specifics that could affect it being marked as duplicated, with additional information on the solution I am trying to garner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Dictionary` class is a generic class with the first type argument corresponding to the type of the keys and the second type argument, the type of the values.

So the dictionary must look like: `Dictionary<string, Sprite>`

Then, you can add a (Key, Value) pair with the `Dictionary.Add(key, value)` method.

So here, you will have:

```
for (int numItem = 0; numItem < someKeys.Count; numItem++)
    dictionary.Add(someKeys[numItem], somevalues[numItem]);
```

But first make sure `someKeys.Count == someValues.Count`.

You could also use LINQ, but it appears that iOS may have limited support for LINQ (see [Using LINQ when building to iOS - Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/376884/using-linq-when-building-to-ios.html))

Comment: I'm beginning to think that this would be a better solution than using Linq when developing for a multitude of platforms (i.e. iOS) from what I've ready about the support around the web. I'll keep an eye on any other updates - though don't expect much as it's been marked as duplicated.

Comment: @LeonardChallis Yes, this is exactly why I used dictionaries. Otherwise I'm a very big fan of LINQ :D
And it's no more flagged as duplicated.